# Deleting the first child using a push() key in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push, message

I am currently working on an app that strictly uses Firebase for the backend. In my app, I want to delete the first message that was written after 30 messages. In other words, I want to allow only 30 messages to be stored. In my firebase database, I have a node called "users", then a node for the user IDs, then under one of the user IDs, I have another node called items. However, I am wanting to delete the first child under the items node, but I don't know the name of that child since I am using the .push() method to set they key for it. Does anybody know how to only delete that first child?

I know HOW to delete a child in Firebase, I just don't know how to access that one child. I've tried something along the lines of:

```
DatabaseReference firstMessage = mDatabase.child("users").child(mUserId).child("items").getRef();
```

Then do this to delete the child.

```
firstMessage.removeValue();
```

I know right after the .child("items") that there should be an additional child but how do i get that key?

Edit: I have come up with a solution, but instead of deleting the first child in the items node, it deletes the first child in the users node

```
DatabaseReference firstMessage = mDatabase.child("users").child(mUserId).child("items").orderByPriority().limitToFirst(1).getRef();
```

Comment: The easiest solution is probably going to be using Cloud Functions for Firebase to write a database trigger that decides, as each item is added, if it should be deleting older items in response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in your onDataChange,

```
for (DataSnapshot p : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    String childKey = p.getKey();
}
```

You can get all the key of all child by this.
you can add them in arraylist or do something else.

If you want to delete some child,
use

```
myRef.child("item").child("childKey_0").setValue(null);
```

==================================

EDIT on 3/4/2017:

I cannot get your new question. Just some example on using the arrayList.

```
ArrayList<String> childKey_list = new ArrayList<>();

for (DataSnapshot p : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    childKey_list.clear();    //clear the arrayList everytime the firebase refresh
    String childKey = p.getKey();
    childKey_list.add(childKey);
}

If (some_method_of_time) {
    String delete_childID = childKey_list.get(0);
    myRef.child("item").child(delete_childID).setValue(null);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this solution and it works, but I need to populate the arraylist in case there are keys already stored when the loadout is created. Any idea how this is done? This is where I got stuck with this method.

Comment: I don't really get your question. But I've update the answer and you can see if it's useful.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will try this method. Would you recommend using a childEventListener? Or would a different kind of listener be needed? Sorry, just starting to learn Android and Firebase!

Comment: I only use childEventListener with a node server.
childEventListener only triggered when there are changes on database. So in your case, if you only control firebase by android, you can use some time method to delete some child. And use childEventListener to detect changes and refresh in your android. 
You may accept my answer if you find it is useful =]

Comment: Okay so i attempted this method, and it works. However, if the user logs in and there are messages already stored in the Firebase Database, the ArrayList is null while the firebase database has values, therefore not allowing me to delete the child that needs to be deleted. It gives me an IndexOutOfBoundsException since the ArrayList is empty. How do i pull those keys from the database and store them back in the ArrayList when the layout is created?

Comment: I am not sure if this is a good method, but I solve this problem by :

First use a listenerForSingleValueEvent to get the message, and then use a valueEventListener/childEventListener to monitor the changes on database.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS - Swift 4

```
    self.ref.queryOrderedByPriority().queryLimited(toFirst: 1).observe(.value, with:{ snapshot in
        guard let key = snapshot.value // as? [String:Any]
        else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
        print("key:",key)
        //key has the first child of a node
    })
```